# HTML code not working on jquery call, instead it outputs HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I call a jQuery function on link click and the function uses the `post()` method to call another page.  I expect to see the rendered html result from other page but instead it shows me the html code of the other page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.thumbnail').click(function(){
        $("div.albums").hide();
        $("div.pics").show();
        var albumid = $(this).siblings('input[name=albumid]').val();
            $.post("gallery-pics-temp.php", { albumid: albumid }, function(data) { 
                $('p#myid').text(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

The other page: (gallery-pics-temp.php)

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['albumid'])) {
        echo $_POST['albumid']; //just for checking if albumid is correct
        $openalbumid = $_POST['albumid'];
        include "config.php";
        //$openalbumid = $_GET['albumid'];
        $querypics = $con->prepare("select * from images where img_albumid='$openalbumid'");
        $querypics->execute();
        $resultpics = $querypics->fetchAll();

        $queryaname = $con->prepare("select * from albums where album_id='$openalbumid'");
        $queryaname->execute();
        $resultaname = $queryaname->fetch();
        $aname = $resultaname['album_name']; 
    ?>

    <div class="pics">
        <a href="/" style="float:left;line-height:50px;color:#fff;"> <<< Back </a>
        <h2 align="center" style="color:#fff;"><?php echo $aname; ?></h2>
        <hr />

        <?php foreach ($resultpics as $row1){ ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail" onclick="showImg(<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>)">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row1['img_path'];?>/<?php echo $row1['img_id']; ?>.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" style="width:200px;height:150px;">  
                </a>
            </div>  
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No it gives empty page, because the code in gallery-pics-temp.php will work only on post['albumid']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `html()` method to add the retrieved data to the page, otherwise it gets encoded. Try this:

```
$('p#myid').html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$('p#myid').html(data)` instead
It should work